# Reading data from sqlite posting it to a .Net webservice to insert the data into sql server

Tags: c#, android, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I would like to get the tables from my device sqlite and post them to a .net web service to insert the data into the central sql server. probably with json.
I use actionscript in flash builder 4.7.
any working code or something seemlier will help a lot . cheers guys.

Comment: it is very urgent guys. appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

so here is what I am on so far. I built the web services/methods and generate the proxy classes for the WSDL and start doing some logic in flash builder to push/pull data across. it is gonna be challenging for those tables that are going bio-directional but looks prety straight forward with the tables going one way only. for one way tables I have to make a work around to take care of identity columns since each table has go and identity/primary column, data coming from different devices with different ranges and sometimes same numbers with primary keys to a single table. I will post the code once I am done. thanks I still appriate if anyone has got a elegant  solutions for it.